# Send an email from an iPhone app containing an img tag

Tags: iphone

I am trying to send the user to the mail app from my native app. I would like the embed a  tag into the body of the message. I know this is possible because the 'LOL Cats' app does it. I have been trying without success:

```
    NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:email@email.com?subject=Check%20Out%20This%20Faux%20Screen&body=<img%20src=\"http://www.sample.com/FauxFoneServer/screenShot/getScreenByID?cur=%@\"/>The%20awesome%20person%20who%20sent%20you%20this%20email%20thinks%20you%20should%20visit%20http://www.fauxscreen.com"
                         ,[ScreenShotsAppDelegate sharedDelegate].viewController.curImage.imageID];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1]];
```

Comment: Have a look at this SO question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531623](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531623)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you call openURL?

You can try encoding the quotation mark (%22), less-than (%3C) and greater-than (%3E) characters.

Comment: Good suggestion but still no go. It does not create an error it simply does not launch the mail app. I tried with no html in the body and it worked fine

Comment: Can you show us a value of 'url1' that fails? Also check if [NSURL URLWithString:url1] is returning nil.